# How to use readarray / mapfile on only a portion of a file?

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, range, lines

I'm working with molecular coordinate files, where the first line is the number of atoms followed by a blank line, and each line following being the x, y, and z coordinates for a given atom.

```
7

O    0    -0.1   -1.5
H    0     0.8   -1.9
H    0     0.1   -0.5
N    0     0      1.5
H    0    -1      1.7
H   -0.8   0.4    1.9
H    0.8   0.4    1.9
```

I would like to create an array where each element is a line of the file, so it would look something like this:

```
r1=(O    0    -0.1   -1.5)
r2=(H    0     0.8   -1.9)
```

I would use the `readarray` or `mapfile` command, but I only want to make elements out of the 3rd through 10th rows. Is there a way to give those commands ranges?

Comment: If either of the provided answers were helpful, you should upvote them, and mark as accepted the one that best answered your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is simple, but note that the lines won't be split into arrays, the output will be a one dimensional array, where each line is an array element.

```
readarray -s 2 arr < file
echo ${arr[0]}
```

will give

```
O 0 -0.1 -1.5
```

to create a two dimensional array requires some additional code, however you can split each line when needed if you have a sequential program.

another approach is filtering the input file for the lines you're interested in (e.g. `sed -n '3,10p' file`)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, though I'm sure it's not the most efficient:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while read line; do
    i=$((i + 1))
    declare -a "r$i"="($line)"
done < <(sed -n '3,10p' coords.txt)

# do stuff with $r1, $r2, etc    
echo "${r1[@]}"
echo "${r2[@]}"
echo "${r3[@]}"
echo "${r4[@]}"
echo "${r5[@]}"
echo "${r6[@]}"
echo "${r7[@]}"
```

We use an [address range](https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/06/sed-simple-pattern-address-usage/) to have `sed` only print the desired line numbers. Feed that into a loop, where we use `declare` to create an array with a variable name.